# How do distribute exams within three weeks?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, optimization

In our program of study we have $N$ students and $M$ courses. I guess $M \approx 50$ and $N \approx 1000$. Each student takes at most $3$ courses in our department. At our university we struggle with the question how one should assign the exam dates of each course within 3 weeks (15 days), such that most student have some days between their exams.

I wonder now if there is some mathematical way to find an optimal solution for this difficult problem.

Edit: I do not know the size $N$ and $M$ at the moment. Of course it would be possible to get this data from the online registration platform of the courses. It would be possbile to get a database where it is shown which student took which course.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have no additional information, spreading the exams evenly over the 15 days is already at least close to optimal, although putting more exams in the first few and last few days and less in the middle may be better.

However, for a real life application you probably know that some courses are very frequently taken in combination while other pairs of courses are practically never combined. Ensuring that students with common course combinations have their exams spread out over the days will probably make a much bigger difference than any optimization with no additional information could give you.

So I would recommend to spread the exams over the 15 days evenly but then look at common course combinations and arrange that these are a few days apart.

Comment: Sorry I think I have not made clear that the additional information is given. I have the information which student takes which course. Of course, if this informaion is missing, then there is not much to optimise ;).